# Ubuntuphone Acquaris E4.5 not recognized

Tags: usb, ubuntu-touch, phone, aquaris, bq

my laptop is Dell XPS-15, with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and:

```
petar@petar-XPS-15-9550:~$ uname -a
Linux petar-XPS-15-9550 4.4.0-103-generic #126-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 4 16:23:28 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
petar@petar-XPS-15-9550:~$
```

my Aquaris E.5 phone is running Ubuntu version 37 (updated on 23rd of December) and all software is the latest.

Here's a `lsusb` from my laptop:

```
petar@petar-XPS-15-9550:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0a5c:6410 Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2b95 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05ac:0304 Apple, Inc. Mighty Mouse [Mitsumi, M1152]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

then I connect the BQ phone with usb cable and I unlock it:

```
petar@petar-XPS-15-9550:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0a5c:6410 Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2b95 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05ac:0304 Apple, Inc. Mighty Mouse [Mitsumi, M1152]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

As you can see they are identical - the phone has not been detected!!!  At the same time the phone indicates that it is charging.
I tried downloading and installing latest libmtp:

```
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/libmtp/libmtp/1.1.14/libmtp-1.1.14.tar.gz

tar -xvf libmtp-1.1.14.tar.gz

cd libmtp-1.1.14/

./configure

make

sudo make install
```

Did not help. Then I tried installing gMTP to see if it will detect it - but nothing was detected. Then I tried `mtp-detect` but nothing was detected:

```
petar@petar-XPS-15-9550:~/libmtp-1.1.14$ mtp-detect
libmtp version: 1.1.14

Listing raw device(s)
   No raw devices found.
petar@petar-XPS-15-9550:~/libmtp-1.1.14$
```

Comment: is the phone set for mtp connection ? or charge only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, as weird as it sounds, I am able to mount my phone after I rebooted the phone. I spent the whole day trying everything that I could think of, but all it took was a simple restart of the phone.

Comment: Sounds like mtpd perhaps got killed on the phone for some reason, and a reboot got the service running again.